# Should you call clear() on a list inside setState or set the list to an empty array?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm wondering how I should clear a list that the UI depends on. Here are two options:

```
//first implementation
setState(() {
  list.clear();
});

//second implementation
setState(() {
  list = [];
});
```

Which one is better? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking I would say look at the clear Method implementation to find out what the method does under the hood. You probably will find arguments why you should use the method.

An easy answer is to generally use provided methods because chanches are that the method is not only for convenience and nice naming but also takes care of some things u are not aware of right now.

Answer (score 0):

Either one is fine but you should know `.clear()` "throws an UnsupportedError, and retains all objects, if this is a fixed-length list." [Source](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/List/clear.html)